# Why does Linux grep not give the correct count for line breaks?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, grep

On Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS, I did the following small test and got a surprising result:

First, I created a file with 5 lines and name it as `a.txt`:

```
echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4\n5" > a.txt
$ cat a.txt
1
2
3
4
5
```

Then I run `wc` to count the number of lines

```
$ wc -l a.txt
5 a.txt
```

However, when I run `grep` to count the number of lines that have line breaks I got an answer that I did not understand:

```
$ grep -c -P '\n' a.txt
3
```

My question is: how does `grep` get this number? Shouldn't it be 4?

Comment: On another Ubuntu system, I did the same test, and `grep` returned 0.

Comment: It should return 0, grep will only search **within** a line. It shouldn't ever see the newline character. Where this 3 comes from is baffling.

Comment: And no, the hypothesis is wrong; if grep did count newlines, it would be 5 not 4. The `echo` will add one more newline. You need the `-n` option if you don't want `echo` to issue a newline.

Comment: Why would you use `grep` when you have `wc -l`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Please Read The Fine Manual!

```
 seq 1 5  | wc -l
 5

 seq 1 5  | grep -ac $'\n'
 5
```

I don't understand where is the problem!?

```
 seq 1 5  | hd
 00000000  31 0a 32 0a 33 0a 34 0a  35 0a                    |1.2.3.4.5.|
```

#### Explanation:

- `-a` switch tell `grep` to open file in *binary* mode. IE *don't care about text formatting*.
- `$'\n'` syntax is resolved by `bash` himself, **before** running `grep`. Doing this give the ability to pass *control characters* as arguments to any command under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash).

Comment: Cool. This works. Would you explain why you use the "-a" option, and why you put a "$" prior to '\n', please?

Answer (score 3):

Grep cannot see new line character. It searches for inline pattern.
Consider using `grep -c -P '$' a.txt` to match the ending of each line.

Comment: You're wrong: `grep -a` work over *binary* files... see [my anser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20932012/1848245)

Answer (score 2):

The newline character is not part of lines. `grep` uses the newline character as the record separator, and removes it from the lines, so that patterns with `$` work as expected. For example, to search for lines ending with `foo` you can use the pattern `foo$` instead of `foo\n$`. That would be very inconvenient.

So `grep -c -P '\n' a.txt` should give you 0. If you're getting 3, that sounds extremely strange, but perhaps it can be explained the **highly experimental** remark in `man grep`:

```
   -P, --perl-regexp
          Interpret  PATTERN  as  a  Perl  regular  expression  (PCRE, see
          below).  This is highly experimental and grep  -P  may  warn  of
          unimplemented features.
```

I'm in Debian/Wheezy, which is much more recent than Ubuntu 10.04. If the `-P` is "highly experimental" today, it's not too difficult to imagine it was buggy in older systems. This is just a guess though.

To count the number of newlines, use `wc -l`, not a `grep -c` hack.

Btw, interestingly:

```
$ printf hello >> a.txt 
$ wc -l a.txt 
5 a.txt
$ grep -c '' a.txt 
6
```

That is, `printf` doesn't print a newline, so after we append "hello" to `a.txt`, there won't be a newline at the end of the file. So `wc -l` counts newline characters, not exactly "lines", and `grep ''` (empty string) matches all lines.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use

```
$ grep -c -P "." a.txt
5
$ echo "6" >> a.txt
$ grep -c -P "." a.txt
6
$ cat a.txt
1
2
3
4
5
6
```